# Building a GeoJSON with Python

Tags: python, json, dictionary, geojson

I want to generate dynamically a geoJSON with a variable number of polygons. Example for 2 polygons:

```
{
    "type": "FeatureCollection", 
    "features": [
      {"geometry": {
          "type": "GeometryCollection", 
          "geometries": [
              {
                  "type": "Polygon", 
                  "coordinates": 
                      [[11.0878902207, 45.1602390564],
                       [0.8251953125, 41.0986328125], 
                       [7.63671875, 48.96484375], 
                       [15.01953125, 48.1298828125]]
              }, 
              {
                  "type": "Polygon", 
                  "coordinates": 
                      [[11.0878902207, 45.1602390564], 
                       [14.931640625, 40.9228515625], 
                       [11.0878902207, 45.1602390564]]
              }
          ]
      }, 
      "type": "Feature", 
      "properties": {}}
    ]
}
```

I have a function which gives me the list of coordinates for each polygon, so I can create a list of polygons, so I am able to build the geoJSON iterating it with a for loop.

The problem is that I don't see how to do it easily (I thought for example in returning the list as a string, but building the geoJSON as a string looks like a bad idea).

I have been suggested this very pythonic idea:

```
geo_json = [ {"type": "Feature",,
              "geometry": {
                  "type": "Point",
                  "coordinates": [lon, lat] }}
              for lon, lat in zip(ListOfLong,ListOfLat) ]
```

But since I am adding a variable number of Polygons instead of a list of points, this solutions does not seem suitable. Or at least I don't know how to adapt it.

I could build it as a string, but I'd like to do it in a smarter way. Any idea?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you can get the libraries installed, django has some good tools for dealing with geometry objects, and these objects have a `geojson` attribute, giving you access to the GeoJSON representation of the object:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/gis/install/

```
>>> from django.contrib.gis.geos import Polygon, Point, MultiPoint, GeometryCollection
>>>
>>> poly = Polygon( ((0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 1), (0, 0)) )
>>> gc = GeometryCollection(Point(0, 0), MultiPoint(Point(0, 0), Point(1, 1)), poly)
>>> gc.geojson
u'{ "type": "GeometryCollection", "geometries": [ { "type": "Point", "coordinates": [ 0.0, 0.0 ] }, { "type": "MultiPoint", "coordinates": [ [ 0.0, 0.0 ], [ 1.0, 1.0 ] ] }, { "type": "Polygon", "coordinates": [ [ [ 0.0, 0.0 ], [ 0.0, 1.0 ], [ 1.0, 1.0 ], [ 0.0, 0.0 ] ] ] } ] }'
```

GeometryCollection can also accept a list of geometry objects:

```
>>> polys = []
>>> for i in range(5):
...     poly = Polygon( ((0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 1), (0, 0)) )
...     polys.append(poly)
...
>>> gc = GeometryCollection(polys)
```

*Update 2019*:

[shapely](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/latest/manual.html#introduction) with [shapely-geojson](https://github.com/alekzvik/shapely-geojson) is now available can may be more easily to introduce as it doesn't required django.

Comment: There is one problem with this approach: I don't know how many polygons are going to be created for each call. GeometryCollection can't be created empty as far as I have been researching. What shall I do?

Comment: just dump your polygons in a list and feed it to GeometryCollection.

Comment: I tried to feed the GeometryCollection with a list of Polygons, but it didn't work. It is working if I create the GeometryCollection with the first polygon and then add the rest of them, but looks ugly. I'm accepting your answer, but please provide and example of how to feed with a list if you can

Comment: see the update, it shows creating a GeometryCollection() using the list, `polys`.

Comment: The link is broken

Answer (score 32):

There is the python-geojson library (https://github.com/frewsxcv/python-geojson), which seems to make this task also much easier. Example from the library page:

```
>>> from geojson import Polygon

>>> Polygon([[(2.38, 57.322), (23.194, -20.28), (-120.43, 19.15), (2.38,   57.322)]])  
{"coordinates": [[[2.3..., 57.32...], [23.19..., -20.2...], [-120.4..., 19.1...]]], "type": "Polygon"}
```

Comment: This answer is excellent, and does mention (which many don't) how to properly create a polygon, with the two brackets around. At least, if you want to read your file in QGIS afterward directly, it seems to be a necessity.

Answer (score 10):

1. Since you've already know how to construct a `point`, it's quite similar to construct a `polygon` object.
2. you could use [`json.dumps`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) to convert a python object to string

Something like:

```
geos = []
for longs,lats in LongLatList
    poly = {
        'type': 'Polygon',
        'coordinates': [[lon,lat] for lon,lat in zip(longs,lats) ]
    }
    geos.append(poly)

geometries = {
    'type': 'FeatureCollection',
    'features': geos,
}

geo_str = json.dumps(geometries) // import json
```